# Calling File.Create() method breaks View() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a MVC action method (Result) that creates a file and calls View().

```
[HttpGet("[action]", Name = "CreateGet")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();    
}

[HttpPost("[action]", Name = "CreatePost")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //saves model value to cookies
            
        return RedirectToRoute("ResultGet");
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet("[action]", Name = "ResultGet")]
public IActionResult Result()
{
    var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(wwwRootPath + @"\result\result.js"))
    {
        var text = "text";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
    }

    return View();
}
```

The result method does create a file, however, rather than going to the Result view it redirects to Create (GET) method. If I comment out the file creation code (using (var fs ...) block), it all works as expected. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

I have done research but I haven't been able to find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Changing something at runtime in your wwwroot folder will have consequnces in the behavior of your app. May be an other path outside the wwwroot folder for result.js is also suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP does not support that. Below is a work demo , you can refer to it.

1.Use Ajax success function to excute the Result action:

```
    @model CreateViewModel
    <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Name" />
        <input asp-for="Id" />
        <button id="sub" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sub").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var Name = $("#Name").val();
            var Id = $("#Id").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Create",
                method: "POST",
                data: { id: Id, name: Name},
                success: function (data) {                        
                     window.location.href = "/Result"; 
                    alert("ok");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

2. Add  file create to Create post action

```
    [HttpPost("[action]", Name = "CreatePost")]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //saves model value to cookies
                
           var wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
           using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(wwwRootPath + @"\result\result.js"))
          {
          var text = "text";
          var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
          var byteCount = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(text);
          fs.Write(bytes, 0, byteCount);
          }
           return Ok("Success");  
        }
        return View(model);
    }
    
    [HttpGet("[action]", Name = "ResultGet")]
    public IActionResult Result()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

result:

[image]